# C++ Fraction Calculator not generating output

Tags: c++

Here is a program I have written that is supposed to get int and char data from a data file corresponding to fractions to be added, subtracted, multiplied, or divided. However, no output is generated when the program is ran with an appropriate data file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void is_negative(int&,int&,int&,int&);
void add(int&,int&,int&,int&,int&,int&);
void diff(int&,int&,int&,int&,int&,int& );
void produ(int,int,int,int,int&,int&);
void divi(int,int,int,int,int&,int&);

      int main()
      {
        int n1,d1,n2,d2;
        int n3,d3 = 0;
        char op; //operator

        cin >> n1 >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> d2;

        while(cin)
          {
            is_negative(n1,d1,n2,d2);

        if((d1 == 0 )||(d2 == 0)) 
          {
            cout << n1 <<  "/" << d1 << " " << op << " " << n2 << "/" << d2 << " = cannot evaluate, 1 or both fractions are invalid" << endl;
          }

        else if(op == '+')
          {
            cout << n1 <<  "/" << d1 << " " << op << " " << n2 << "/" << d2 << " = " << endl;
            add(n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3);
          }
        else if(op == '-')
          {
            cout << n1 <<  "/" << d1 << " " << op << " " << n2 << "/" << d2 << " = " << endl;
            diff(n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3);
          }
        else if(op == '*')
          {
            cout << n1 <<  "/" << d1 << " " << op << " " << n2 << "/" << d2 << " = " << endl;
            produ(n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3);
          }
        else if(op == '/')
          {
            cout << n1 <<  "/" << d1 << " " << op << " " << n2 << "/" << d2 << " = " << endl;
            divi(n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3);
          }

        cin >> n1 >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> d2;
          }
        return 0;
 }

void is_negative(int& n1, int& d1, int& n2, int& d2)
{
  if(d1 < 0)
    {
      d1 = -2 * d1;
      n1 = -1 * n1;
    }
  if(d2 < 0)
    {
      d2 = -1 * d2;
      n2 = -1 * n2;
    }
}

void add(int& n1, int& d1, int& n2, int& d2, int& n3, int& d3)
{

  d1 = d1 * d2;
  d2 = d2 * d1;
  n1 = n1 * d2;
  n2 = n2 * d1;
  n3 = n1 + n2;
  d3 = d2;

   cout << n3 << "/" << d3 << endl;

}
void diff(int& n1, int& d1, int& n2, int& d2, int& d3, int& n3)
{
  d1 = d1 * d2;
  d2 = d2 * d1;
  n1 = n1 * d2;
  n2 = n2 * d1;
  n3 = n1 - n2;
  d3 = d2;

   cout << n3 << "/" << d3 << endl;

}
void produ(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int& n3, int& d3)
{
  n3 = n1 * n2;
  d3 = d1 * d2;

  cout << n3 << "/" << d3 << endl;
}

void divi(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int& n3, int& d3)
{
  if(n2 != 0) 
    {
      n3 = n1 * d2;
      d3 = d1 * n2;
      cout << n3 << "/" << d3 << endl;
    }

  else
    {
      cout << "division by 0 is not defined" << endl;
    }
}
```

I would expect this program to generate output statements, since all data inputted will go to one of the four calculator functions, all ending with a print statement. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably comment those functions as they are very confusing.

Comment: It will be much easier if you define a data structure for fractions so you can write `Fraction x = add(fraction1, fraction2);` (If this is school work, it may be required for a passing grade.)

Answer (score 1):

The program seems to be printing fine if I just enter the numbers and the operator in the expected order. I would suggest to check the input file and see if its indeed sending it in the format you expect

Comment: Use eclipse or Visual Studio, set a breakpoint 
, and step through the code line by line. You can see and watch exactly what it is doing

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your input format. Following above codes, the operator and operate should be separated by the " " or enter character.

P/s: These codes output -> wrong result. You should check 4 calculation functions.